# How do I change the background color with javascript using the text within a button

Tags: javascript

```
/** HTML File **/
<button id="blue" onclick="colors()">blue</button>


/** JavaScript File **/
function colors() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor=
        document.getElementById('blue').value;
}
```

"button" contains the text, "blue"

I'm trying to have the background color equal to that text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` instead:

```
function colors() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('blue').innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="colors('blue')">blue</button>

<script>
/**
 ** @param {String} color - The color you want to change to
 **/
function colors(color) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an input instead

```
/** HTML File **/
<input type="button" id="blue" value="blue" onClick="colors();"></input>


/** JavaScript File **/
function colors() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor=
        document.getElementById('blue').value;
}
```